# configparser python

Tags: python

При попытке записать данные в ини файл, старые данные из него стираются. Почему так? В документации всё работает, а у меня нет. Вот часть кода, отвечающая за это:

```
config['DEFAULT']['path'] = filedialog.askdirectory()

    with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

там есть параметр window_size, но он стирается, как только я записываю это

Кстати, если я создаю какую-либо секцию кроме как [DEFAULT], выходит ошибка о том, что такой секции нет

Answer (score 0):

> При попытке записать данные в ини файл, старые данные из него стираются.

Данные, которые хранятся в вашем файле, перезаписываются, так как вы используете ключ `w`.
Вам нужен ключ на добавление, то есть `a` - > `with open('config.ini', 'a')`.

Ключ `a` откроет файл для добавления нового содержимого. Или же создаст новый файл для записи, если не найдет с указанным именем.

Подробнее вы можете прочесть [здесь](https://pythonru-com.turbopages.org/pythonru.com/s/osnovy/fajly-v-python-vvod-vyvod)

Если вы хотите видоизменить в секции значение ключа, то сделайте так:

```
config.set('имя секции', 'window_size', '0')
```

Тогда оставьте запись на открытие файла прежним:

```
with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

Comment: нет, таким образом у меня добавляется новая секция, а нужно изменить в старой только определённый ключ
config.ini
[DEFAULT]
mta_path = C:/Games
window_size = 0

Comment: Да и проблема не меняется, даже когда добавляешь новое, только один ключ меняется

Comment: @GreenPy я дополнил ответ, посмотрите.